# Find the maximum value of a dense vector set it to 1 and all the rest to 0 [pyspark]

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame column containing dense vectors. I would like to set the maximum value of a those vectors to 1 and replace all the rest to 0.
For example:

```
+------+-------------+
|  Col1|       vector|
+------+-------------+
|Modali|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|assert|[4.0,9.0,3.0]|
+------+-------------+
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
+------+-------------+
|  Col1|       vector|
+------+-------------+
|Modali|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|
|assert|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
+------+-------------+
```

Note that I'm working on spark 2.1.0, using python.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `udf` that takes in a vector and binarize it; The binarizer can be constructed by simply checking if the value in the vector is equal to the maximum value using a list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def max_binarizer(vector):
    max_val = max(vector)                              # maximum value in the vector
    return Vectors.dense([1 if x == max_val else 0 for x in vector])    # binarize it

# create a udf for the binarizer
max_bin_udf = F.udf(max_binarizer, VectorUDT())

df.withColumn("vector", max_bin_udf(df["vector"])).show()
+------+-------------+
|  Col1|       vector|
+------+-------------+
|Modali|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|
|assert|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|
+------+-------------+
```